# Does using Azure Service Bus filters on a Subscription incur the cost of an operation?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

If a single Azure Service Bus Topic with 10 subscriptions exists. I put a Message on the Topic and it goes to all 10 subscriptions. From the docs I assume this incurs the cost of 10 operations.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/service-bus

However if we added a filter to all 10 to only allow certain Messages, would it still incur the cost of one operation regardless, i.e to process the filter even if the Message does not go on the Subscription?

Answer (score 0):

> if we added a filter to all 10 to only allow certain Messages, would it still incur the cost of one operation?

Yes even if we are using filters on a subscription and if we receive message from a topic, i.e., **message retrieval after abandon**, **deferral** or **dead lettering** will be counted as independent operations and will considered as billable operations.

So, it will incur an operational charge assuming all messages are delivered to all subscriptions.

Comment: So if its filtered out thats not a cost incurred? Any source for this?

Comment: No, it will be charged even its filtered out.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a docs URL source for this I can show to the boss :)

Comment: I could not find documentation that specifically points this out. However, as @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT alluded to, a message must be placed into a topic in order for filtering to take place. Thus that will incur an operation cost.